# Iterating Effect Size Calculations Through Columns

Tags: r, for-loop, lm

I am currently comparing the size of 159 regions (ROI) in the brain between an at-risk and normal population on R. I originally calculated lm model p-values using this loop:

```
storage <- list()
for(i in names(ThalPC)[-c(1:8)]){
  storage[[i]] <- lm(get(i) ~ Status, ThalPC)
}

table <-  storage %>% tibble(
    dvsub = names(.),
    untidied = .
    ) %>%
  mutate(tidy = map(untidied, broom::tidy)) %>%
  unnest(tidy) 

tab <- as.data.frame(table)

to <- subset(tab, select = -c(2))

newtable <- filter(to, term == "StatusControl")
```

ThalPC= my data frame
Status = Their status as Control or at-risk population

Now, I have around 59 regions with significant p-values and I am hoping to calculate the effect sizes for them. Currently I am trying to use this loop:

```
stor <- list()
for(i in names(ThalPC)[-c(1:9)]) {
  stor[[i]] <- lm(get(i) ~ Status, ThalPC)
try <- effectsize(stor[[i]], type="eta")
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in get(i) : object 'Left_LGN' not found
```

(Left_LGN being a region that I am studying, all the 159 regions are set up as columns through the data frame)

Perhaps I am overthinking it, does anyone know any simple solution/ better approach to getting the effect sizes for them?

I am still a beginner in R and statistics so I really appreciate your input!!
Thank you!

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide a working example of you data (see:https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess you used `attach(ThalPC)` before running your first script to add columns of ThalPC to the search path. Instead, try constructing your call to `lm` as:

```
stor[[i]] <- lm(as.formula(paste(i, "~ Status")), 
    data = ThalPC)
```

It looks like you might want to collect the output of `effectsize` as elements of a list too, otherwise you're overwriting it each time.

Comment: that worked perfectly! Thank you!! And great point, I made it a list in my final code.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow @Jane. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. :)